# Auto Increment Id in stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get company id like "Cp-00001". If data exists in table then the id should be "Cp-00001" + 1 = "Cp=00002" and do on...

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AutoGenerateCustomerCode] 
 AS
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
    SELECT @id = 'Cp-' + CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(CompanyCode,4,5) AS INTEGER))+1 AS VARCHAR) FROM [Beauty Saloon Project].[dbo].[tbl_Company];
    IF @id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @id = 'Cp-00001';
    END

    RETURN @id;
END
```

but when i call it here

```
  datatable DT = new datatable
  DT = ExecuteSpDataTable("sp_AutoGenerateCustomerCode");
```

This returns `null`.

If I don't have data then it should return Cp-00001, but I have one data row in which company code is saloon is it the reason for null ???

EDIT:

```
public DataTable ExecuteSpDataTable(string SPName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ConnectionOpen())
            {
                SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SPName, objConnection);
                objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                SqlDataAdapter objSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
                objSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = objSqlCommand;
                objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable);
                ConnectionClose();
                return objDataTable;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objErrorLogs.LogError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just create an auto-incrementing, numeric identity column? You're setting yourself up for a world of pain by trying to roll your own.

Comment: the problem is obviously in your c# code, since the stored procedure you described will never return NULL

Comment: some times things to be dome on requirement other wise i will not do it just having head ache :(

Comment: what is the error in c# code just calling sp

Comment: what is ExecuteSpDataTable ? Why do you use this and not ExecuteScalar ?

Comment: i got error in SP here is the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cp-1' to data type int." how to remove it ?

Comment: @Thomas i have edited my post please check it out

Comment: what happens if you run the procedure in SqlServer Managment Studio (i.e. outside of your c# code). I believe you should still see the conversion error, but can you confirm?

Comment: @SaluSala for example the company code is 'Cp-00001', or '00001' ? Because substring might be the problem is the first one is company code.

Comment: @Chris i am getting this error in sql management studio "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cp-00001' to data type int."

Comment: Any reason for down voting my post ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word of advice: ***DON'T DO THIS!*** Using this `SELECT MAX() + 1` approach is not safe under load, as soon as more than one user will be using your application, you **WILL HAVE DUPLICATES** - sooner or later.

The only viable solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CompanyID AS 'CP-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCompany(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CompanyID` will contain values like `CP-00001`, `CP-00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

**Update:** if you want to make the `CompanyID` the primary key, you could use this T-SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   CompanyID AS 'CP-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED
      CONSTRAINT PK_tblCompany PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Company ON dbo.tblCompany(ID);
```

I would leave the clustered index on `ID` and just move the primary key constraint to use `CompanyID` instead.

Comment: You sir have so elegantly cleared my long standing confusion similar to question posed... Thanks

Comment: @marc_s sorry i do not have enough reputation to vote up your answer when i would have i will vote it :)